# Google Map Inside viewpager and a vertical scroll view not getting displayed in some devices

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I have a viewpager with 5 fragments and one among them is a search fragment with a google map the weired issue is that in some device the map is displayed with no problem but in some device(micromax aq 5000 Kitkat) it's not getting displayed

fragment

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainlayerr"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ScrollView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_MenuLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"


             >
             <AutoCompleteTextView 
                   android:id="@+id/txtSearchh"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_2_5_x"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_2_5_x"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_2_5_x"
                   android:hint="Search"
                   android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                   android:padding="5dp"
                   android:background="@null"
                   android:textColor="@color/markerboxcolor"


                   />
             <View 
                 android:layout_height="1dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_2_5_x"
                 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_2_5_x"
                 android:background="@color/divider_color"

                 />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >



                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_0_x"

                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/space_2_x" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkimage_male"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:text="Male"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                         />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkimage_female"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                         android:text="Female"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                         />
                </LinearLayout>
          </RelativeLayout>
           <HorizontalScrollView 
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrolll"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="#C6D7D2" android:layout_height="80dp">

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                     android:orientation="horizontal">        
    </LinearLayout>
           </HorizontalScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/distance_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_tabs_container_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sportsViewPager"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/container_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_2_x"
                    android:layout_weight="0.15"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/distance"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_2_x"
                        android:gravity="left|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_2_x"
                        android:text="@string/search_dist"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color1x"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_tabs_container_height"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_2_x"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <com.sportspartners.sportspartners.util.DiscreteSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekBarr"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_weight="1"

                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_2_x"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/space_2_x"
                         app:dsb_allowTrackClickToDrag="false"
        app:dsb_indicatorTextAppearance="@style/CustomFloaterTextAppearance"
        app:dsb_progressColor="@color/my_progress_color"
        app:dsb_rippleColor="#FF7788FF"
        app:dsb_indicatorColor="@color/my_floater_color"
        app:dsb_indicatorFormatter="%d" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/progressID"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_2_x"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_2_x"
                        android:text="10 Kms" >
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>



            <View
                android:id="@+id/seprater1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/from_menu"

                android:background="@color/blue" />   
                <FrameLayout 

                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/seprater1"
                    >          
            <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mappy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"


    android:name="com.sportspartners.sportspartners.fragments.search.SearchFragment"


        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
            <View
            android:id="@+id/imageView123"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@android:color/transparent" />       

           </FrameLayout> 
        </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>   


 <ListView 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      android:divider="@null"
      android:scrollbars="none"
      android:id="@+id/searchhList"
     android:visibility="gone"
      ></ListView>

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/progress_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"


        android:visibility="gone"
        />
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/messagenotificationlayout"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/searchhList"
           android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            >
          <com.example.floatinglibrary.FloatingActionButton

         android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/chatterimage"
      app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="#00000000"

               android:id="@+id/messagenotificationbtn"
             android:background="@null" 
            app:fab_size="normal"



         />
            <TextView

                 android:background="@drawable/blue_circle"
                 android:id="@+id/messagenotificationbadge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:gravity="center"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
             android:paddingTop="5dp"
             android:paddingRight="5dp"

             android:layout_marginLeft="-17dp"

             android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:padding="2sp"
              android:clickable="false"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_micro_min"

                />

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

 parent layout with view pager
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titlecontainer"
         >
     <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/titlbarrSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@color/markerboxcolor"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"


         >
         <ImageButton 

             android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
             android:id="@+id/btnsearchback"
             android:src="@drawable/searchback"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:background="@null"
             />
         <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/txttitle"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:text="Search"
             android:textColor="@color/pure_white"
             android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
             />
         </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/titlbarr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@color/markerboxcolor"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:weightSum="5"

        android:gravity="center"


         >
         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              >
          <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/txt1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Feed"
        android:gravity="center"

         android:textColor="@color/tabred" 
             />
          <View 
              android:layout_height="4dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:background="@color/tabred"
              android:id="@+id/view1"
              />
          </RelativeLayout>
         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              >
          <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/txt2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Profile"
       android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="#ffffff" 
             />
           <View 
              android:layout_height="4dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:background="@color/pure_white"
              android:id="@+id/view2"
              android:visibility="gone"
              />
          </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              >
          <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/txt3"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Search"
        android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="#ffffff" 
             />
           <View 
              android:layout_height="4dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:background="@color/pure_white"
              android:id="@+id/view3"
              android:visibility="gone"
              />
          </RelativeLayout>
              <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              >
          <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/txt4"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Followers"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="#ffffff" 
             />
           <View 
              android:layout_height="4dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:background="@color/pure_white"
              android:id="@+id/view4"
              android:visibility="gone"
              />
          </RelativeLayout>
              <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              >
          <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/txt5"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="#ffffff" 
             />
           <View 
              android:layout_height="4dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:background="@color/pure_white"
              android:id="@+id/view5"
              android:visibility="gone"
              />
          </RelativeLayout>

     </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.sportspartners.sportspartners.util.MyViewpager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titlecontainer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
     <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_headerr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/markerboxcolor"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</com.sportspartners.sportspartners.util.MyViewpager>




</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: my display in kikat device]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer google map will not show up(in some devices) if it's placed inside a scroll view for that I need to set   android:fillViewport="true" inside scroll view this may stop scrolling the map but will show it to a perfect size